# Cant upload photos and store them as blob to mysql

Tags: java, mysql, spring, blob

I am trying to upload a photo with html and store it as a blob using Spring JPA
this is my ORM class.

```
@Entity(name = "Option")
  @Table(name = "options")
    public class Option {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(
            strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY
    )
    @Column(
            name = "id",
            unique = true,
            updatable = false
    )
    private Long id;


    @Column(
            name = "img_name",
            nullable = false,
            columnDefinition = "TEXT"

    )
    private String imgName;



    @Column(
            name = "img_description",
            nullable = false,
            columnDefinition = "TEXT"
    )
    private String imgDesc;

    @Lob()
    @Column(
            name="img_src",
            columnDefinition = "bytea"
    )
    private byte[] imgSrc;




    public Option(String imgName, String imgDesc) {
        this.imgName=imgName;
        this.imgDesc=imgDesc;

    }

    public Option() {

    }


    public byte[] getImgSrc() {
        return imgSrc;
    }

    public void setImgSrc(byte[] imgDesc_i) {
        this.imgSrc = imgDesc_i;
    }

    public String getImgName() {
        return imgName;
    }

    public void setImgName(String imgName) {
        this.imgName = imgName;
    }

    public String getImgDesc() {
        return imgDesc;
    }

    public void setImgDesc(String imgDesc) {
        this.imgDesc = imgDesc;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Option{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", imgName='" + imgName + '\'' +
                ", imgDesc='" + imgDesc + '\'' +
                '}';
    }

    public Option(Long id, String imgName, String imgDesc) {
        this.id = id;
        this.imgName = imgName;
        this.imgDesc = imgDesc;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
```

> and here is my form

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/add}" th:object="${option}"  method="post">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="hidden" th:field="*{id}" class="form-control" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Description</label>
                    <input type="text" th:field="*{imgDesc}" class="form-control" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Image name</label>
                    <input type="text" th:field="*{imgName}" class="form-control" required>
                </div>
                <div  class="form-group">
                    <label class="form-label" >Upload image</label>
                    <input th:field="*{imgSrc}"  type="file" class="form-control"  />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <a href="/admin" class="btn btn-info" role="button">Cancel</a>
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Save">
            </div>
        </form>
```

and this is my controller

```
@PostMapping("/add")
    public  String addOption(@ModelAttribute("option") Option option) {
        optionService.save(option);
        return "redirect:/admin";
    }
```

The problem is that I keep img src in Option class as array of bytes.
at MySQL dbms shows that type of imgSrc  is  blob

so when I am trying to save using jpa repository, it just saves image name.
could someone help me to solve issue?
thank You

Comment: Does an exception occur on save? Also have you confirmed `optionService.save` has the byte array filled in on the `Option` object?

Comment: there is no exception , its just save image name.

Comment: I  just used simple template of  jpa 

 public void save(Option tmp) {
        optionRepository.save(tmp);

    }

Yes. byte array exists

Comment: Might be easier to have a "form" object used that your form posts to instead of the entity directly. In your form object you could use a `MultipartFile` and then when you persist to the database just create an `Option` entity object and call `setImgSrc` with the `MultipartFile.getBytes()`

Comment: thank you for your response. I will try and comment back

Comment: I understand the logic of saving an entity. but I can't realize how to post in form both my object and MultipleFile could you send example of form?

Comment: You would create an `OptionForm` that your html binds and posts to and use that as your `@ModelAttribute` in your `addOption` method. The `OptionForm` would have the `MultipartFile` field in it. That would correspond with your `<input type="file"...` html element. Then you would create an `Option` object based off of the `OptionForm` object and call your `optionService.save(option)` method as you're already doing.